# Design pattern for java wrapper for Jquery datatables

Tags: java, jquery, datatables, design-patterns

I have found the Jquery datatables plug in extremely useful for simple, read only applications where I'd like to give the user pagination, sorting and searching of very large sets of data (millions of rows using server side processing).

I have a system for reusing this code but I end up doing the same thing over and over alot. I'd like to write a very generalized api that I essentially just need to configure the sql needed to retrieve the data used in the table. I am looking for a good design pattern/approach to do this. I've seen articles like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359750/jQuery-DataTables-in-Java-Web-Applications and have a complete understanding of how server side processing works (have done it in java and asp.net many times). For someone to answer you will probably need to have a deep understanding of how server side processing works in java but here are some issues that come up with attempting to do this:

- I generally run three separate queries. A count without the search clause, a count with the clause included, the query for the actual data. I haven't found an efficient way to do all 3 at once and doing so requires a lot of extra data to come back from db (ie counts over and over). The api needs to support behavior based on these three different queries and complex queries at that. I generally row number () over an index for the pagination to be relatively speedy with large data.

*where clause changes dynamically (user can search over a variable number of rows).

*order by clause changes for the same reason.

- overall, each case is often pretty specific to the data we need. Is there a good way to abstract this so that I can do minimal work when I want to use the plug in server side.

So, the steps are as follows in most projects:
*extract the params the plug on sends to the server (alot of times my own are added, mostly date ranges) 
*build the unfiltered count query (this is rarely dynamic). 
*build the filtered count query  (is dynamic) 
*build the data query 
*construct a model object of the table and return it as json.

A lot of the issues occur setting the prepared statements with a variable number of parameters. Dynamically generating the sql in a general way (say based on just column names) seems unlikely. I am wondering if someone else has created something they are using for this or if it sounds like a specific pattern is applicable. It has just occurred to me that creating a reusable filter may be helpful in java. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to be language agnostic as the architecture is what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have base search criteria where all request parameters relevant to DataTables are mapped onto class properties (fields) and custom search criteria class that extends base and contains specific to business logic fields for sutom search. Also on server side we have repository class that takes custom search criteria as an argument and makes queries to database.

If you are familiar with C#, you could check out [custom binding code](https://github.com/tssoft/TsSoft.Web/blob/master/TsSoft.Web/Mvc/DataTablesNet/DataTableModelBinder.cs) and [example of usage](https://github.com/tssoft/TsSoft.WebSamples/blob/master/TsSoft.WebSamples/TsSoft.WebSamples/Controllers/WebController.cs).

You could do such custom binding in your Java code as well.